# Visual Studio creating extra lines

Tags: visual-studio-2010, text, ide, formatting

I've looked at several threads here on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but I can't seem to check the right box to fix this formatting problem.  Everyone else on the dev team formats like this:

```
<Setter TargetName="Header" Property="Padding" Value="0" />
```

and when I use **Edit >>Advanced >>Format Document** (or generally when I am creating new code) it formats like this:

```
<Setter TargetName="Header" 
Property="Padding" 
Value="0" />
```

I'm sure most everyone can understand the importance of everyone's coding looking similar especially when it's time to integrate.  In some cases mine is more simple to read, but it stretches out the code so much it's intolerable.  Does anybody know what setting I use to fix this?  I've already played around in **Tools >>Options >>Text Editor >>C# >>Formatting** for over half an hour last night.  I'd be quite happy to set it back to original settings...

Comment: That looks like XML, not C# - why do you think changing the C# formatting options will help?

Comment: Yes, good catch.  I don't know why I didn't see this.  It would still be great to be able to reset to original settings.  Especially since I mucked around with the C# formatting trying to fix my xaml formatting.

Comment: Unfortunately I next mucked around with the XAML settings and aside from being able to take out extra blank spaces, I cannot get VS to everything between < and > on the same line.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx

Comment: @Oded The reset did not help my original issue (described above) but I appreciate knowing how to do the reset.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure you're in the correct section of the options: **Tools >>Options >>Text Editor >>XAML >>Formatting>>Spacing**.  *Position each attribute on a separate line* and *Position first attribute on same line as start tag settings* both help this issue.  Thanks to @oded for pointing me in the right direction.  Others take note so you don't make the same mistake.